# Using Nagios check_log command doesn't work

Tags: nagios, logfiles

Firstly, sorry for my english.

I try to configure a probe in nagios for monitor log files and notify me when Nagios find string like "Exception" or "Error". 
I use Nagios with Centreon.

So, when I execute my command : 
**$USER1$/check_log -F path/for/log.files -q /Exception/**

Nagios return : **"Log check error: Log file path/for/log.files does not exist!"**

When i check in my server the path, the files exists, all (root, group and other) can read the file. So the problem doesn't seem to come of rights management.

The client for supervisor is a CentOS. I have already install nrpe client, and configure allowed host etc ...

I looked everywhere for someone who had the same error but find nothing. 
If someone can help me, it would be so nice !

If you need further informations for help me, please, don't hesitate, i'm not sur that i'm explain in good way my problem.

Regards.

Comment: So, I understand the problem, i check log in my nagios server where the path and the file don't exist, so now, the problem is what i need to do for check in my server client of supervisor 
Someone ?

Answer (score 0):

On Nagios server side, you must define something like this:

```
define service {
       service_description            service_name
       host_name                      your_remote_hostname
       use                            your_template
       check_command                  ext_check!check_log!-f path/for/log.files -g /Exception/ 
}
```

In commands.cfg or in similar file on Nagios server:

```
define command{
    command_name    ext_check
    command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -t 30 -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 5666 -c $ARG1$ -a $ARG2$
    }
```

On client/monitored host you must edit nrpe.cfg file:

```
command[check_log]=/opt/nagios/plugins/check_log $ARG1$
```

after that, you must restart nrpe service and reload Nagios configuration.

Comment: Thanks you for answering ! I try to use with NRPE and i think it's finally work 
Have a nice day